# Magento chain of inheritance. Good or bad practice?

Tags: php, oop, magento, object

I'm just starting with Magento (1.9) I have read that Magento is OO designed, which is a good point, but after digging a bit into the core and some third party modules, it is weird to me that classes inherit others in chain (this can reach up to 4 or 5 levels of inheritance).

Is this a good practice?

```
final class I4_TaskManagerOrderXml_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Button_Runnow_Orderxml     extends I4_TaskManager_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Button_Runnow_Import {}
```

class I4_TaskManager_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Button_Runnow_Import     extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field {
//some stuff
}

class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field     extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Abstract     implements Varien_Data_Form_Element_Renderer_Interface {
//some stuff
}

class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Abstract extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
…
}

Comment: please use namespaces, so you can shorten those overly long class names to something workable...

Answer (score -1):

Magento uses very much layers of abstraction so it makes it more flexible for third party developers to hook into the code.

(Almost) every class in Magento can be rewritten by extensions. This means that you can easily add your own method to existing classes without having to touch the core code.

As in terms of OO: the amount of layers of abstraction used are different for each platform. For example, a product Model in Magento has the following chain:

- `Varien_Object`, which is a class that's famous for the magic getter- and setter functionality of Magento
- `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`, which adds basic model functionality (such as loading and saving).
- `Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract`, which adds basic catalog functionality for products and categories for example.
- `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`, which is a basic product.